# How to do regex substitution only on some arbitrary field you specify

Tags: perl, unix, command-line, sed, awk

What I love about awk is you can fetch all the lines from a file that satisfies the condition on some aritrary field you specify.
For example,

```
awk '$3~/hi/' < test.txt # print all lines where the third field matches the pattern "hi"
```

or

```
awk '$2>=2' < test.txt  # print all lines where the second field is greater or equal to 2
```

As a beginner who's learning about the power of unix, I am absolutely fascinated about this. 
Now I am wondering if there is an easy way to perform regex substitutions only on some arbitrary fields you specify? For example, I want to do regex substitution on the third field only. 
my current method is to "cut" the field I want and perform substitution on that using perl or sed, which then I "paste" to the original file. But I am wondering if there is more efficient way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged this question with 'perl' (in addition to 'sed', 'awk', 'unix', and 'command-line'), I'll assume you're interested in answers that incorporate any of the above tools.

Perl has an auto-split command-line switch (`-a`):

```
perl -lane 'print if $F[2] =~ /some pattern/' filename
```

...or...

```
perl -lane 'print if $F[1] >= 42' filename
```

`-a` causes an auto-split into the `@F` array.  `-n` causes Perl to iterate over the lines of the file you feed it.  The rest is programming. ;)

Now for substitution:

```
perl -i.bak -lane '$F[2] =~ s/match/subst/; print join q/ /, @F' filename
```

Or, a little shorter using the `-p` switch, which tells Perl to print each line as it appears in `$_`.  That means if you alter `@F`, you'll have to copy it back into `$_`:

```
perl -i.bak -pale '$F[2] =~ s/match/subst/ && $_="@F"' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e 'Fred barney Wilma\nfoo bar baz' |
awk '$2 == "barney"{sub(/b/,"B",$2)};1'
Fred Barney Wilma
foo bar baz
```

You can use the `sub`, `gsub` commands or this this case:

```
echo -e 'Fred barney Wilma\nfoo bar baz'|
awk '$2 == "barney"{$2="Barney"};1'
Fred Barney Wilma
foo bar baz
```

Just substitute the second field completely.

N.B. The `1` at the end of the line is shorthand for `{print}`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simple example:

`awk -F "," '{ OFS=","; sub ("1", "x", $3); print $0 }' file.txt > newfile.txt`

`newfile.txt` will now contain:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
8,9,x0,11,12,13,14
15,16,x7,18,19,20,21
```

Here, `1` was replaced with an `x` in the third column `$3`.
`-F ","` sets the delimiter of the input file. 
`OFS=","` adds a comma to the output.

If you would like to make the substitution globally, consider using `gsub` instead of `sub`.

HTH

Comment: I think it would be better to set value for `OFS` once and before reading input file in the `BEGIN` block, like `awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS="," } { sub ... }'`